# How to call variable in jquery to put inside {{ Storage::url() }}

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, laravel-8, datatables-1.10

i have datatables in laravel 8 and i was encode a table to get some atribute, the code like this
[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bg5l.png)

i want to call r.file to get value for access the path of file,
the path file like this = "assets/file/Dr3cxy0QM2GDH1IpaWeiMZDUXfTVhl6QkazEyKYh.pdf"

[Blade View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SQU7.png)

but the result like this
[Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW1vM.png)

how to make the href value like this?

`<a href="/storage/assets/file/Dr3cxy0QM2GDH1IpaWeiMZDUXfTVhl6QkazEyKYh.pdf">Test.pdf</a>`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the jQuery `.data()` method to store the data in an HTML element and then access the data using the `.data()` method in the jQuery selector.

For example, if you have an HTML element with a class of `storage-url` and you want to store a variable called "url" in it, you could do the following:

```
<div class="storage-url" data-url="{{storage::url(url)}}"></div>
```

Then, in your jQuery code, you can access the data using the `.data()` method:

```
var url = $('.storage-url').data('url');
```